# Django & HTMX - make forms render_field a target of HTMX

Tags: python, django, django-forms, htmx

I've created a django form where user can input partial name of a client. HTMX displays all matching clients and when button is pressed next to clients name, I'd like it to fill multiple form fields. Let's consider simplified Django manual form example:

***invoices/templates/invoice_add.html***

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}
<form method='POST' autocomplete='off'> {% csrf_token %}
    <label>{{ form.number.label_tag }}</label>
    {{ form.number.errors }}
    {% render_field form.number class="form-control" %}
    <br>

    <label>{{ form.buyer_name.label_tag }}</label>
    {{ form.buyer_name.errors }}
    {% render_field form.buyer_name class="form-control" hx-post="/invoices/check_client/" hx-trigger="keyup" hx-target="#buyer_names_list" %}
    <div id="buyer_names_list"></div>
    <br>

    <label>{{ form.buyer_tax_no.label_tag }}</label>
    {{ form.buyer_tax_no.errors }}
    {% render_field form.buyer_tax_no class="form-control" %}
    <br><div id="tax_no_test"></div>

    <input type='submit' value='save'/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

As mentioned above, when populating `buyer_name` I'm getting a list of client names with a button next to their name inside `buyer_names_list`. This button calls below function to pull the tax number:

***invoices/views.py***

```
class InvoiceCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name: str = 'invoice_add.html'
    form_class = InvoiceForm
    queryset = Invoice.objects.all()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)


def particular_client_invoice(request):
    client_obj = Client.objects.all().filter(name=request.POST.get('clientname'))
    context = {'client_tax_no': client_obj.values_list('tax_no', flat=True)[0]}
    return render(request, 'partials/specific-invoice.html', context)
```

## My issue:

While it properly returns desired tax number, I can only return the values from HTMX inside a div (`id="tax_no_test"` in this case). I'd like field `form.buyer_tax_no` to be the target field of the tax number. Is that possible? Alternatively (worse scenario), the value could be added to POST request another way, the `render_field` won't need to be displayed at all.

In case any additional code is required please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One way to handle this is to call the same form view and use hx-select to get only the specific field from the rendered html. The `client_tax_no` (from POST) would be passed as initial value to this form. Can you provide the view code which renders the form, so we can see if that's a feasible solution?

Comment: Just added the code above in `invoices/views.py`, although it's just a simple class based view. If needed, I can pivot towards function based views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find some time to come back to this problem. While the solution is not perfect (quite ugly actually) and not as scalable as I'd like it to be, for now this is the best I've got.

I've installed the django-crispy-forms - I recommend a [pretty decent series on integrating it & htmx on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZwKoi0wu2Q). I've replaced the entire **invoices/templates/invoice_add.html** to become a simple crispy form and then I was able to set the divs of the form to become a target of `hx-target` attribute of HTMX button/span.

The ugly part is that I can't get it to replace only the `value` attribute of the html div in the form, therefore currently in the template partial I include the entire HTML of the initial div, which is risky (changing `forms.py` requires a change in partials aswell). Also, in case I'd like to do that with multiple fields, it will get messy.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my preferred approach.

Change the `hx-post` to `hx-get` and point it to the same view. When making htmx request, it should include url query with the input value.

Then override the `get_initial` method of the view to set the initial value of your field (you can additionally check if the request is of htmx type, just to make sure):

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super().get_initial()

    if 'clientname' in self.request.GET:
        client_obj = Client.objects.all().filter(name=self.request.GET.get('clientname'))
        initial['buyer_tax_no'] = client_obj.values_list('tax_no', flat=True)[0]

    return initial
```

You will get the full form html response, from which you can retrieve the `buyer_tax_no` field by using `hx-select` by pointing it to your field's ID.

The target would be the same id but you probably will need to change the swap type to outerHTML (another way is to wrap the input field around with div/span and use it to both select and target the element).

If you only want to return the partial content including your field, you would need to override the `render_to_response` method with something that generates partial content like [django-render-block](https://github.com/clokep/django-render-block) or [django-template-partials](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-template-partials)

Having that, you also need to handle a case where submitting the form causes full refresh, in case of an invalid form.

---

Of course, there could be a few other ways to handle it, like:

- only calling the url and using js to set the value
- using a dedicated view where you only render the specified field

The reason for my solution is that allows you to reuse already existing logic.

If the logic gets more complicated, I would consider rewriting the view to FBV though, things can get wild & messy pretty fast with CBVs ;)

Comment: thanks - I've overwritten the `get_initial` method and tried editing the `render_field` `form.buyer_tax_no` to utilize the `hx-select` but I have no clue how this attribute works and what triggers it. the documentation only shows example with a button and since it doesn't work with any sort of `hx-trigger` I'm not sure how should I do it. would you mind providing a working, simple example of this form? apologies, I'm very new to HTMX and AJAX too, honestly.  
I'm thinking that scraping existing logic and creating dedicated view to render specified field would probably be a better idea.

Comment: hx-select takes specific part (provided by attr value) of html from your response coming from htmx request. You can use a dedicated view instead, to retrieve the same part also. I think you should rewrite your code, to FBV to make it more readable. Also seems like you've resolved the issue, so up to you.